# Prove there is no bijective holomorphic $f:\mathbb D\setminus\{-1/2,1/2\}\to\mathbb D\setminus\{0,1/2\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> Prove that there does not exist a bijective holomorphic function $f:\mathbb D\setminus\left\{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}\to\mathbb D\setminus\left\{0,\frac{1}{2}\right\},$ where $\mathbb D$ denotes the open unit disk in the complex plane.

I have no idea how to start solving this problem. Could anyone please provide a hint on how to get started on this problem or point me to a Theorem that I must find a way to apply?

---

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

A hint to start you off: show that the singularities at $-1/2$ and $1/2$ are removable.

Comment: Thanks you for your help. In order to achieve this I think I can use Riemann's Theorem on Removable Singularities, and prove that the function is bounded near $-1/2$ and $1/2.$ I believe I can do this by using the same argument used the Theorem in Gamelin's. That is, expanding as a Laurent series, and then using the Cauchy ML-estimates. Would this work? If you don't mind me asking, why would this lead to a contradiction that $f$ cannot exists?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to fill in the details:

Such an $f$ would map $D$ bijectively onto itself, whereby the set $\bigl\{-{1\over2},{1\over2}\bigr\}$ is mapped onto $\bigl\{0,{1\over2}\bigr\}$. Now such an $f$ would leave the hyperbolic distance in $D$ invariant. On the other hand
$$d_{\rm hyp}\bigl(-{1\over2},{1\over2}\bigr)=2\,d_{\rm hyp}\bigl(0,{1\over2}\bigr)\ .$$